# Finalizar thread que está bloqueado en un .receive()

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer en Java para finalizar un thread que está bloqueado esperando recibir más información.

```
 DatagramSocket socket = null;
 while(true){

 packet = new DatagramPacket(bufferDatagram, bufferDatagram.length);
 socket.receive(packet);

}
```

Comment: Puedes usar un timeout al inicializar el socket con el tiempo en milisegundos:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress%29 Espero que te sirva!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una variable de control , en este caso un `bool` te hace el trabajo.

```
 DatagramSocket socket = null;
 boolean fin = true;
 while(fin){

 packet = new DatagramPacket(bufferDatagram, bufferDatagram.length);
 socket.receive(packet);

}
```

Cuando quieras que termine el bucle , simplemente cambia el valor de la variable `fin`

EDIT:

Si tu `socket`sigue esperando, puedes usar la propiedad `setSoTimeout` para indicarle un tiempo maximo de espera. Una vez el tiempo pase puedes hacer varias cosas como gestionar excepciones ya eso depende de ti.

```
       socket.setSoTimeout(1000);   

        while(fin){        
            try {
                socket.receive(packet);

            }
            catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {

                System.out.println("Ups! timeout " + e);
                socket.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, así lo he probado ya también, el problema es que hasta que no reciba 1 vez más algo, no vuelve a intentar dar la vuelta, entonces no sale del bucle, me explico?

Comment: @diego he actualizado mi respuesta a ver si esto te ayuda.